# Struts 1 and Compilation

Tags: java, struts-1

Learning struts 1 and facing one situation. Have tomcat server and struts 1 softwares. I am unable to compile Struts Action class in command prompt. Using,

```
D:\sample_struts_application>javac -classpath D:\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.30\common\li
b\*.jar;D:\struts1.1\jakarta-struts-1.1\lib\*.jar CustomerAction.java
CustomerAction.java:1: error: cannot find symbol
public class CustomerAction extends Action
                                    ^
  symbol: class Action
CustomerAction.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping , ActionForm form, HttpServle
tRequest request,
                             ^
  symbol:   class ActionMapping
  location: class CustomerAction
CustomerAction.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping , ActionForm form, HttpServle
tRequest request,
                                                     ^
  symbol:   class ActionForm
  location: class CustomerAction
CustomerAction.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping , ActionForm form, HttpServle
tRequest request,
                                                                      ^
  symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
  location: class CustomerAction
CustomerAction.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
^
  symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
  location: class CustomerAction
CustomerAction.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping , ActionForm form, HttpServle
tRequest request,
       ^
  symbol:   class ActionForward
  location: class CustomerAction
CustomerAction.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
CustomerForm cust = (CustomerForm)form;
^
  symbol:   class CustomerForm
  location: class CustomerAction
CustomerAction.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
CustomerForm cust = (CustomerForm)form;
                     ^
  symbol:   class CustomerForm
  location: class CustomerAction
8 errors
```

Why it is not compiling?. Struts jars are correctly given. What is the reason?

Comment: If you get this error on line number 1, you are probably missing import statements.

Comment: It's a action class.

Comment: public class CustomerAction extends Action.

Comment: this action class, dont have any imports.

Comment: You have to import everything that is not in `java.lang`. Such as `Action`, `ActionMapping`, `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you learning Struts 1.1? Struts 1 was EOLed five years ago, and the last S1 release (1.3.10 maybe?) was ten years ago.